# Userform Listbox, fill dynamically

Tags: excel, dynamic, listbox, range, vba

I have `Userform Listbox` object. Everytime I start `Userform` select some options and then open second `Userform` with `Listbox`. According to options set in `Userform 1` is adding items to `Listbox`. `Listobox` should be dynamically filled with certain data.

Problem rises when I close second `Userform` and start it once again - `Listbox` becomes blank. I thought it is due to not cleared items but it looks like it is not the point...

Edit (9th June 2014):
Problem is even funnier: when I use step by step method using code it does work. When I start it normally it stops showing data in listbox :(

This is code for 2nd `Userform`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim MyCell As Range
Dim jaki_kraj As String

jaki_kraj = Klient_kraj.kraj.List(Klient_kraj.kraj.ListIndex, 1)

Dostawcy_listbox.Clear

With Dostawcy_listbox
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "140;40"
End With

i = 0

'tworzy listę dostawców dla aktualnie wybranego kraju
For Each MyCell In Range("dostawcy").Cells

    If MyCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = jaki_kraj Then 'jeżeli dostawca ma wpisany VAT dla kraju
        Dostawcy_listbox.AddItem MyCell 'to dodaj go to listy
        Dostawcy_listbox.List(i, 1) = MyCell.Row
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next MyCell

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

skip_quit = False
Dostawcy_listbox.Clear
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using array.

```
zmienna_dost = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks("Testowanie_fak.xlsm").Worksheets("Dostawcy").Range("D1:D" & lastrow1), Mid(nazwa_arkusza, 1, 2))

ReDim dostawcy_arr(0 To zmienna_dost, 0 To 1) As String

For Each MyCell In Range("dostawcy").Cells

    If MyCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = jaki_kraj And _
    IsEmpty(MyCell.Offset(0, 3)) = False Then 'jeżeli dostawca ma wpisany VAT dla kraju
        dostawcy_arr(i, 0) = MyCell
        dostawcy_arr(i, 1) = MyCell.Row
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next MyCell

With Dostawcy_listbox
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "140;39"
    .List = dostawcy_arr
End With
```